# SQL server 2014 query running slow on client java application, runs fast on database server

Tags: java, sql-server

We have recently migrated from sql server 2012 enterprise edition to sql server std edition as we are not using any enterprise edition features. The java application (JEE 6) runs on JBoss 7.2 community edition with JDK 1.7 in centos 7 (64bit) server. The database is MS SQL 2014 STD and runs on windows server 2016. Both application and database run vmware. 
The compatibility mode of MS SQL server was set to 110 initially and we got good performance. We checked to see the performance by setting compatibility mode to 120. BY switching to 120 compatibility mode, all the queries are running very slow despite we rebuild all the indexes, clearing cache, update statistics.

Resetting to 110 does not give any better results. Most interesting observation is when the same application runs on database server machine itself, the queries are running fast.

Checked the network, reinstalling the DB, VM do not give any improvement. Do not have any clue about this strange behavior.

We are using tools like hibernate (4.3), using sqldialect2012.

Are we missing any configuration setup (jdbc/hibernate), database settings in this client-server environment so that we can get consistent behavior from SQL server.

Please help to understand the root cause of this weird performance problem.

Comment: http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

Comment: Are you calling a stored procedure from Java, and running the content in SSMS?  Maybe look into parameter sniffing.

Comment: No, Only JDBC call. Updated to MS sql jdbc driver 6.2, still the performance is erratic. We got good performance just after migration from 2012 to 2014 with compatibility mode set to 110. The hell breaks just after we set the compatibility to 120.